# Accept or deny cookies - how to?

Tags: cookies

As far as cookies privacy policy has been change, i need to make a script which allow to accept (or not) cookies by user for this domain (website) only. Is there a way to do this for one website only.

Second thing is this popup window should be displayed only if user came from different domain (so each page have to check it - template/header).

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is regarding the new EU cookie policy, you only have to worry about third party tracking cookies that track between sites, WordPress cookies don't fall within that category.

Comment: Yes, exaclty, but could you explain this to me please? Website is for solicitors, and i need to write good explanation for them.

Comment: @miszczu read this, it should help: http://boagworld.com/site-content/the-eu-cookie-law-what-to-do-now/